# Is there an automated way to compare two .jar files to get java related infos?

Tags: java

I know that I can just extract a .jar contents and thus compare it to another one.
Nevertheless this process has two flaws, in my opinion:

1)It is tedious: I have to manually compare them.

2)It does not give me important information like, for example, the jdk version .class files were compiled against or, in case of .war files, any specific environment they were optimized for.

So I ask: is there any program which actually takes in .jar/.war files and tells me the differences in such a manner?

Comment: I'd start with searching library for extracting such information from single `jar` instead of diff-tool. It seems to be very specific and doesn't exist.

Comment: We normally use "Beyond Compare" for this kind of job

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are *specifically* off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Try asking here instead: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ... but make sure that you state the requirements clearly, as per the site's Help Centre.